# PHP function __autoload($class_name) how to Load two class path directories

Tags: php

I am using following function to autoload classes, it works fine if i am using only one directory called 'classes' however when i try to use Smarty lib also it fails and give me the error

```
Fatal error: Class 'Database' not found in /home/...
```

for ex:

```
require_once(DOC_ROOT."/libs/Smarty.class.php");
function __autoload($class_name) {   
    require_once( CLASS_LIB."/".$class_name . '.class.php');
}
$db = new Database();
$session=new Session();
$smarty = new Smarty();
```

but if i do this it give me the error unable to load the smarty class..

```
function __autoload($class_name) {   
    require_once( CLASS_LIB."/".$class_name . '.class.php');
    require_once(DOC_ROOT."/libs/Smarty.class.php");
}

$db = new Database();
$session=new Session();
$smarty = new Smarty();

Warning: require_once(/home/.../classes/Smarty_Internal_TemplateCompilerBase.class.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/.../includes/init.php
```

Any idea what i am i doing wrong here ? i need to be able to load classes directory automatically but needs to make sure i dont loose smarty path too..

Comment: I'd advise against using __autoload as it only lets you register a single autoload method.  The addition of spl_autoload_register has pretty much made __autoload redundant, and provides more flexibility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solve the problem spl_autoload_register function two times.

below is the code for reference.

```
spl_autoload_register('load_api');
spl_autoload_register('load_lib');

function load_api($class){
    if(!file_exists(CLASS_LIB."/".$class. '.class.php') )
        return false;
    require_once( CLASS_LIB."/".$class. '.class.php');
    return true;
}
function load_lib($class){
    if( !file_exists(DOC_ROOT."/libs/Smarty.class.php") )
        return false;
    require_once(DOC_ROOT."/libs/Smarty.class.php");
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Several solutions come to mind.

- Use include_once instead of require_once to avoid the error.
- Check for the existence of the file before doing the require_once.
- Put in an if statement detects Smarty and special cases the code.
- Just include the Smarty classes manually.
- (Best) Use spl_autoload_register twice, once for your classes and once for the Smarty classes. __autoload is deprecated. Spl_autoload_register should handle the problem.  http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php